# Every time I run VIM, "help.txt" opens automatically

Tags: vim

I'm afraid asking this silly question but google looks like has no answer for this.

Every time I run VIM in terminal it automatically opens "help.txt" file with sp(split screen) mode.
It says "help.txt" "help.txt" [readonly] 217L, 8055C
Does anybody knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: this can also be due to a mouse keycode conversion issue, specifically if it happens everytime you focus vim loaded in a terminal emulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running:

```
vim -u NONE
```

If this help file doesn't appear when doing that, then there's something in a vimrc file somewhere that is opening the help. Check in:

```
~/.vimrc
/usr/share/vim/vimrc
/etc/vimrc
```

...and anywhere else you might find a `vimrc` file on your system.

Comment: I found out that I typed 'h' in some line by mistake.

Comment: I still have this issue. Every time i open and file using vi editor, At some point of my mouse click the help.txt opens up at the top screen.I am stuck now. Any help ?

Comment: Using a VirtualBox guest on Windows, pressing the Host Key to detach and then click in a Vim PuTTY Window with TERM set to screen-256color opens :help. This still happens with vim -u NONE so it is NOT configuration-related. I am puzzled why this happens. Pressing CTRL+V (reading keypresses) and going back and forth between VirtualBox and the clean terminal window with CTRL+V doesn't output any keys pressed. It does not happen in native Windows Vim. It does not happen with $TERM / Terminal-string in PuTTY data set to `linux` but it does happen with `screen-256color` and also `xterm`

Comment: What is the solution for this issue??

Comment: any solutions for this issue? @dezza did you resolve this?

Comment: @Manachi for VirtualBox no. I think its the keycode translation that fails. For other cases it might be a terminal emulator not following xterm specification or an incorrectly set $TERM

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behaviour except my environment is using conemu for WSL on Windows 10 (not VirtualBox)

Answer (score 17):

in my case it was because I am using app called [caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/index.html) (prevents PC from sleeping) which is simulating pressing F15. After I change it status to inactive, it stopped opening vim help in terminal window.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, that's exactly the issue I'm having!

Comment: yes, same issue at my end also. This idea did not click in me until I saw this answer. Thank you

Comment: How can I keep caffeine active and keep working in VIM at the same time? I have my own .vimrc which isn't doing anything special with F15 key. Yet it keeps popping up the help.txt. Any way to do this?

Comment: Never in a million years I would've guessed that. You're the man!

Comment: Nice. Mine was a vb-script running numlock on a loop. Also to keep the PC from sleeping.

Answer (score 4):

if you run
$ vim -u NONE

and the issue persists, maybe (like in my case) is some software simulating a key press to prevent the system from sleep.

try to change it for another key, like shift, and not f15.

good luck!

Comment: In my case I had a script running in the background to cycle NumLock and prevent the screen from sleeping, but it  constantly triggered the Help menu using vim inside of Putty. Thanks!

Comment: How can you make VIM ignore the F15 key? I have my own .vimrc that isn't doing anything special with F15, and would like to keep caffeine app active